# Collection view inside a collection view

Tags: swift

As of title, I'm having trouble with the issue of nesting collectionViews. I found a workaround gimmicky solution but I'm not really satisfied with the result:

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var outCollection: UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    outCollection.dataSource = self
    outCollection.delegate = self
  }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = outCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "outCell", for: 
indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
cell.backgroundColor = .green
cell.setViewDD() // gimmick HERE
return cell
  }
}
```

and for the CollectionViewCell

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var inCollection: UICollectionView!
func setViewDD() {
    self.inCollection.delegate = self
    self.inCollection.dataSource = self
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = inCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "inCell", for: indexPath) as! innercellulosa
    cell.backgroundColor = .red
    return cell
  }
}
```

if I try to set the delegate and datasource of the innerCollection (either in VC3 or CVCell) I stumble in multiple problems which I can't solve.

Comment: You don't want to make a CollectionViewCell the delegate/dataSource for a collection view, for many reasons, including for example there should only be one object that is the delegate, one that is the dataSource (maybe the same object) and you have 4 cells, they can't all be the delegate/dataSource.

Comment: @Shadowrun That's exactly my problem, if I try to set VC3 as my delegate/data source I stumble in the following problems : if I put the outlet in VC3 -> cannot use outlet in repeating content; if i put outlet in CVcell i don't understand how I should set the delegate/datasource, since I can't access the outlet from the VC3 file. My nose tells me that there is a way to specify an external file as a delegate/datasource (inCollection.delegate = file.swift) and call it from the cellForItemAt function... I'm ignoring something important here... the problem is I don't know what.

Comment: Make a "class InColDataSource: UICollectionViewDataSource", whose only job is to be the data source for your "inCollection"  collection view.  Within VC3, have an array (self. myDataSources) of those data source objects. When you make an inCell, programatically set the cell's cv's data source to myDataSources[n]